# Query Xdocument

Tags: soap, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I have a soap message from an web service as an Xdocument and wish to extract the session id element for future use. I am able to loop over the the response using the code below,  but how would I query the soap to return the sessionid

```
Dim dnas = From node In Responce.DescendantNodes _
       Select node


        For Each node In dnas
            If TypeOf node Is XElement Then
                Debug.Print(DirectCast(node, XElement).Name.ToString)
            Else
                Debug.Print(node.ToString)
            End If
        Next
```

The soap:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<CreateResponse xmlns="http://myweb.com/webservices">
<CreateResult>
    <ResultCode>0</ResultCode>
    <ResultDescription>Authentication Successful</ResultDescription>
    <sessionid>04e1b723-ff93-4af0-94f4-2245ccf11f42</sessionid>
  </CreateResult>
</CreateResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
XNamespace ws = "http://myweb.com/webservices";
string sessionId = (string)Response.Descendants(ws + "sessionId").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, that helps a lot.